# Enity framework code first model not updating right entity in the database

Tags: entity-framework, nopcommerce

I am using ef code first model in a mvc app, i have to model one is product, temp_product. my edit view for product is bind with product model. show all the changes done by user will be in product model. Now in controller i am copying all updated value from product model and setting  them to temp_product and calling the function to update the entity temp_product in the database. but what is being happening is my product table is being updated while temp_product contains old value. how can i solve this?

to copy entity value i used..

```
public class Sync
{ 
   public static void CopyProperties(dynamic product, dynamic tempProduct) 
   { 
      PropertyInfo[] productPI = product.GetType().GetProperties(); 
      PropertyInfo[] tempProductPI =tempProduct.GetType().GetProperties(); 
      foreach (PropertyInfo temp_prodPI in tempProductPI) 
         foreach (PropertyInfo prodPI in productPI) 
         if (prodPI.Name == temp_prodPI.Name && temp_prodPI.CanWrite) 
         temp_prodPI.SetValue(tempProduct,prodPI.GetValue(product,nul‌​l), null); 
   }

_temp_productRepository.Update(temp_product);
```

and in Update function

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
if (entity == null)throw new ArgumentNullException("entity"); 
this._context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please show code that is more directly related to the problem, like how you copy the values to the entity object. Also: the title and the problem description do not seem to match.

Comment: to copy entity value i used..public class Sync{ public static void CopyProperties(dynamic product, dynamic tempProduct)
{
 PropertyInfo[] productPI = product.GetType().GetProperties();
 PropertyInfo[] tempProductPI =tempProduct.GetType().GetProperties();
 foreach (PropertyInfo temp_prodPI in tempProductPI)
   foreach (PropertyInfo prodPI in productPI)
       if (prodPI.Name == temp_prodPI.Name && temp_prodPI.CanWrite)
temp_prodPI.SetValue(tempProduct,prodPI.GetValue(product,null), null);
}

Comment: actually my view is being bind with Product model so changes are mapped in that entity, to update temp_product entity i copied all property and updated.

Comment: Please move the code to the question body.

Comment: Did you solve the described problem. If yes - please elaborate.